# Caching mechanism in Javers on a distributed system

Tags: javers

I understand that there is a cache implemented in Javers to store the globalId and CdoSnapshot, namely LatestSnapshotCache. But I'm not sure about it's behaviour in a distributed system. Our application uses mongoDB on multiple nodes, I'm not sure whether this cache will have a major impact in this scenario. Please guide me here. Also, can we have our own custom cache to boost performance instead of this. For example, a Hazelcast cache.

Answer (score 0):

LatestSnapshotCache is a simple (guava) local heap cache and 
there is no way to plug a distributed cache (like Hazelcast) or another impl of local cache. Agreed that it could be useful but i'm doubt about distributed caches, Mongo is a really fast database. Again, I agreed that the cache could be pluggable.

LatestSnapshotCache is safe in distributed systems, because snapshots are immutable.